# What is a fragment size in an ext3 filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, ext3

This is an output from dumpe2fs:

```
root: ~/# dumpe2fs -h /dev/sdb3 | grep -i 'fragment|block size'
dumpe2fs 1.39 (29-May-2006)
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Fragments per group:      32768
```

Is this related to disk fragmentation?

Answer (score 11):

No. ext3fs doesn't support block fragmentation so a one byte file will use a whole 4096 block.

On the opposite, for example [UFS supports multiple fragments](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-5093/fsfilesysappx-10/index.html) in a block so small files won't fill a file system as fast as they will do on ext3fs.

This is unrelated to [file system fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_fragmentation) which is about file data blocks not being contiguous and sequential.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The mkfs manual is very cryptic-only a one liner for the "-f fragment-size" option. If block fragmentation is not supported in ext2/3/4, why does the -f option appear in the mke2fs manual? Nothing serious, just curious.

Comment: Just in case someone want to implement it. See the BUGS section in the very same manual page: `mke2fs  accepts the -f option but currently ignores it because the second extended file system does not support fragments yet.`

Comment: It is one of those things that was put in as a planned feature, but never implemented.

Comment: @psusi: actually, it's one of those things that was put to make ext2fs more like UFS and FFS. Probably noone ever expected it to be implemented in the future.

Comment: At least the manual page writer expected it to be implemented.

Comment: @ninjalj, they put it in because they expected ext2fs to be similar to UFS and have the feature.  If they knew it would never be implemented, it wouldn't have been put in.

Comment: Not unrelated to disk fragmentation though. Per Oracle Solaris' doc (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-5093/fsfilesysappx-10/index.html) : "The ability to allocate fragments of blocks to files, rather than just whole blocks, saves space by reducing fragmentation of disk space that results from unused holes in blocks."

Comment: @ChennyStar Solaris documentation talks about storage efficiency when referring to disk fragmentation. This is not the usual meaning of [fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_fragmentation) which is not about storage efficiency (space) but sequential file access performance (seeks). Nowadays, this is less of an issue because more and more file systems are on SSDs where seeks are "free".

Comment: @jlliagre : I know, and I agree. It just goes to show that the term fragmentation can have different meanings in different contexts. In any case, I also put the link to Oracle's doc, because it's a concise description of what a fragment is in FFS/UFS

Comment: @ChennyStar Thanks, answer updated.