# debug mkfs.ext3 command output

Tags: filesystems, ext3, mkfs

I was creating a new file system in my external HDD. While formatting, I had to format this partition to the remaining available partition which is somewhere around **850GB**. Now, I created an `ext3` file system in this partition. This is the output of my `mkfs.ext3` command.

```
mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb3
mke2fs 1.41.3 (12-Oct-2008)
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
52060160 inodes, 208234530 blocks
10411726 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=4294967296
6355 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
        102400000

Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

Can someone help me debug the information as am not clear on what these values actually represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let us use the bytes notation to understand the concepts. Now, the actual size of the external HDD was *850GB* which translates to *912680550400* bytes.

**Block size and fragment size**

The block size specifies the size that the file-system will use to read and write data. Here the default block size of *4096* bytes is used. The ext3 file system doesn't support block fragmentation so a one byte file will use a whole *4096* block. This can be modified by specifying the `-f` in the `mkfs` command but it is not suggested as the file systems today have enough capacity.

```
Total blocks possible = 912680550400/4096 = 222822400 blocks
```

So in our command output we have actually got *208234530* blocks which is pretty close to our calculation and because there will always be some blocks that cannot be used.

```
Total inodes in this example = 208234530/4 = 52058632.5 inodes
```

As per derobert's comment, the total inodes is the number that `mkfs` is actually creating. `inodes` on ext2/3/4 are created at `mkfs` time. We can change how many it creates with several options (`-i`, `-N`) and different `-T` options do so implicitly.

It is always a heuristic and so the total inodes possible as per our command is *52060160* inodes.

```
Maximum file system size possible = 4294967296 * 4096 (block size)
```

So theoretically the file system size can be upto *16 TB* but however, it is not true.

The size of a block group is specified in `sb.s_blocks_per_group blocks`, though it can also calculated as `8 * block_size_in_bytes`. So total block groups possible could be,

```
total block groups = 208234530/32768 = 6354.81
```

So it is close to *6355* groups as per our command output.

```
Total inodes per group = 32768/4 = 8192 inodes
```

**References**

http://www.redhat.com/archives/ext3-users/2004-December/msg00001.html

https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout

https://serverfault.com/a/117598

[What is a fragment size in an ext3 filesystem?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16307/what-is-a-fragment-size-in-an-ext3-filesystem)

Comment: Please verify the answer and if there is something wrong, let me know. If there are any contents worth adding, you are welcome to add it too :)

Comment: It's not total inodes possible, it's the number that mkfs is actually creating. inodes on ext2/3/4 are created a mkfs time. You can change how many it creates with several options (`-i`, `-N`) and different `-T` options do so implicitly. Also, it should probably be 2³²-1 (4294967295)...

Comment: @derobert, thanks for providing the information. I have added the information you gave and edited the answer.