# What can f_bsize be used for? (Is it similar to st_blksize?)

Tags: stat

`stat()` on a file, returns several fields including `st_blksize`.  This is documented as "the 'preferred' block  size  for  efficient filesystem I/O".  The value is not used as a unit for other `stat()` fields, or referred to anywhere else in the POSIX standard.

`statvfs()` on a file, returns several fields including `f_bsize`.  It also returns `f_frsize`.  `f_frsize` is the unit for `f_blocks`, `f_bfree`, and `f_bavail`.  `f_frsize` is variously called the "fundamental file system block size", and the "fragment size".

My man pages for `statvfs` describe `f_bsize` as the block size of the filesystem.  This basically tells me nothing.  The introduction already told me that statvfs() returns information about the filesystem as a whole.

1. What can `f_bsize` be used for?  What does the filesystem block size mean, if it is not equal to the "fundamental filesystem block size"?
2. Is `f_bsize` the same thing as `st_blksize` on Linux and BSD and/or UNIX?  Let's ignore the possibility of a FUSE filesystem contrived with the sole reason of breaking this rule.  And the same for NFS servers.  I'm also not very concerned that `f_bsize` represents a filesystem-wide value, which might be overridden for specific files.
3. Am I right to think that unlike `st_blksize`, POSIX does not suggest any particular meanings for `f_bsize`?

Comment: This field exists. It is reasonable to think that there was likely a reason it was created, and ask what that reason was. No?

Comment: Apparently not. I will explicitly say that I wanted this answer as research for the answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463322/29483 , which seems to have some uncontroversial usefulness.  Would really appreciate any feedback how to write a better Q&A for this research!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeBSD documents the following:

> `f_frsize` - The size in bytes    of the minimum unit of allocation on
>                 this file system.  (This corresponds to the `f_bsize` member of `struct statfs`.)
>
> `f_bsize` - The preferred length of I/O requests for files on this
>                 file system.  (Corresponds to the `f_iosize` member   of
>                 `struct statfs`.)
>
> The statvfs() and fstatvfs() functions fill the structure pointed to by
>        buf with garbage.  This garbage will occasionally bear resemblance to
>        file system statistics, but portable applications must not depend on
>        this.
>
> The statvfs() and fstatvfs() functions conform to IEEE Std    1003.1-2001
>        (``POSIX.1'').  As standardized, portable applications cannot depend on
>        these functions returning any valid information at all.  This implementation attempts to provide as much useful information as is provided by the
>        underlying file system, subject to the limitations of the specified data
>        types.

The `stat` command in GNU coreutils can also show "fundamental block size" and "block size".  It documents the latter as "(for faster transfers)".

I expect these are all accurate to the original meanings.  The POSIX documentation for `st_blksize` says "In some file system types, this may vary from file to file".  This suggests one reason why POSIX avoids specifying `f_bsize` as having any particular meaning.  (Another is the concept of block size might not make the same sense on some filesystems, e.g. UIBFS)

`f_bsize` could also have some use if you're familiar with the specific filesystem implementation that you're querying.

### Original meaning of `f_frsize` as "Fragment size"

It seems the description "fragment size" should be understood as originally referring to fragments on filesystems like [UFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_File_System).  These are an allocation unit smaller than a "block".  See [What is a fragment size in an ext3 filesystem?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16307/what-is-a-fragment-size-in-an-ext3-filesystem)

Based on this, it seems `f_frsize` will usually be smaller or equal to `f_bsize`.

Linux ext2/ext3/ext4 did not support fragments.  Some Linux filesystems [may report a smaller `f_frsize`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/coreutils/+bug/412074).  Although that was a FUSE filesystem under development, and I don't know what it was or why it wanted to use "fragments" / `f_frsize`.